# When you want to scrape a web page, what if the target tag is hidden by ellipsis?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x

I'm trying to scrape a web page. I have found the tag I want by inspecting the elements on the page. But when trying to scrape it using BeautifulSoup, the target tag is hidden.

Here's the target tag hidden by ellipsis:
[target tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGOxD.png)

And here's my code:

```
url = 'https://www.jisilu.cn/data/cbnew/cb_index/'
txt = requests.get(url)
txt.raise_for_status()
txt.encoding = 'utf-8'
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt.text, "html.parser")
body = soup.find('body')
div1 = body.find('div', attrs = {'class': 'grid data_content'})
div2 = div1.find_all('div', attrs = {'class': 'grid-row'})[1]
td = div2.find('td', attrs = {'valign': 'top'})
div3 = td.find('div', attrs = {'id': 'cb_index'})
div3
```

Output:

```
"div class="cbindex_quote_info" id="cb_index" style="margin-left:60px;margin-right:20px;width:700px;display:inline-block;font-weight:bolder;">.../div"
```

As you can see, the wanted content is hidden. Can I get possible solutions to this problem

Comment: That means there are children. Click on the arrow beside it to expand its contents.

Comment: Sorry for leaving this for so long. Actually the reason was that these contents are generated by javascript. A solution is to use the selenium package in python. Have a good Thanks giving!

Answer (score 0):

Iterate `<a>` to get all the data from the children spans

or use `element.encode_contents()`

```html
<a title="点击查看明细" href="/data/cbnew/cb_index/" target="_blank">
转债等权指数：
<span style="color:red;">1265.389↑&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span title="涨跌">+7.360</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span title="涨幅">+0.590%</span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
平均价格 <span title="平均价格">120.295</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;转股溢价率 <span title="平均转股溢价率">21.20%</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;到期收益率 
<span title="平均到期收益率">-0.91%</span></a>
```

Comment: Hi, could you give more hints on how you got the result? Cuz this is what I wrote: 
` code `div3.encode_contents(formatter = "html")`code`

And this is what I got:

Out[48]:
b'...'

The problem seems that all the span tags are hidden.

Answer (score 0):

When i have this problem i usually swap `find_all()` for a `select()` function

```
url = 'https://www.jisilu.cn/data/cbnew/cb_index/'
txt = requests.get(url)
txt.raise_for_status()
txt.encoding = 'utf-8'
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt.text, "html.parser")
body = soup.find('body')
div1 = body.find('div', attrs = {'class': 'grid data_content'})
div2 = div1.find_all('div', attrs = {'class': 'grid-row'})[1]
for tds in div2:
    td = div2.select('td')
    for td in tds:
        div3 = td.get('id')
        if div3=='cb_index':
           #some more code
```

It is a little longer, but i find it usually works for me with no time differential that I have noticed.

If you noticed that it may be because some part of the HTML element is missing then consider adding a modified version of the code below to whatever element is hidden

```
div2.select("input[type=hidden]")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I got an error saying that there shouldn't be an 'attrs' attribute in the function "select". Also, I think the problem isn't finding the div3 here, but looking into what's inside div3. Anyway, thank you for your help!